# Android apache client logging in

Tags: android, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am developing an app.
On the first screen user have to log in (POST call) and then on other screens it can perform actions (GET calls).

I am doing it in asynctask, but the problem is, I have to log in in background on every screen, becasue async task (and therefore the client instance) is destroyed after performing a call. Is it possible to send instance of HttpCLient between activities?

The second approach, I have tried was IntentService, but after I make a GET call, intentservise sent me response and close itself. And after recalling I need to log in again.

And I was wondering.

Is it possible to log in once in some backgroud thread, that is alive until the app is alive and then just sending GET calls from UI thread and receiving responses?

Or is it better to log in in every activity, but don't bother device with background thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you login then store the session value in `sharedPreference` until user log out. Its better approach rather sending the request to web server for authenticate again again.

Comment: I have my session ID (there is a special GET call, that returns it, so I don't have to bother with cookies).
http://localhost:8080/gwt-console-server/rs/identity/sid
(can it be what I need?). It's basically just a long String value.
Can you please tell me what to do with it? The thing with sharedPreference is clear, just how to "add" this value to Client session.

Comment: @user2142090 Look at this example that will give idea http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/